# How to get back my routes.rb(accidentally deleted) file in rails?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rubymine

I accidentally deleted my routes.rb file. Lots of code were there. Is there any way to get back routes.rb file?

Comment: i don't know how to recover the file... but you can use this http://artmees.github.io/rm/ not to make the same mistake again ;)

Comment: See if it's in your rubymine local history. You should be using source control and/or backing up.

Comment: Just restore it from version control. You *were* using version control, right???

Comment: just got the file from dropbox. thank you for suggestion :)

Comment: No, I am not using version control system. But I will use it from now :) @Mark Thomas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think we need some more information. Specifically:

- How did you delete the file?
- Approximately how many lines of real code did you lose?
- Are you using any form of version control (Git? Mercurial?)
- Do you have any other forms of backup for your files?

If you're not backing up your information, this is going to happen and it's going to be terrible. I strongly advise you to start using [Git](http://git-scm.com/) (and [Github](https://github.com/)) if you aren't already, to prevent this from happening in the future.

Comment: got the file :). Fortunately the app was connected with dropbox. Just restored the file from dropbox site. Thank you for your answer and advise :)

Comment: No worries, glad you got your data back! Dropbox is a great backup utility, but I'd still recommend Git and Github. Both are free, and they can help you not only save your work securely, but also to track the changes that you've made and revert them if need be. Very nice when working with partners.